# program crashed on ucrtbase.dll!_abort()

Tags: c++, qt

It is a Qt desktop application.
And dump files was collected from user side.

Open the dump file with visual studio, got the call stack:

```
    ucrtbase.dll!_abort()   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    ucrtbase.dll!_terminate()   Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
>   AAAAA.exe!__scrt_unhandled_exception_filter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS * const pointers) Line 93   C++ Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    KERNELBASE.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()    Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  Unknown Non-user code. Symbols loaded.
```

This is the exception message:

Unhandled exception at 0x7578EDBB (ucrtbase.dll) in AAAAA.exe.1652.dmp: Fatal program exit requested.

the name of my application is XesStudent.exe.
And I have also checked the logs, but found nothing.

**Question is how to Check the problem?**

Comment: You have an uncaught c++ exception in a thread. Can't tell much more without a [mre]

Comment: It is a user side crash, I only have the dmp file and some logs, can't reprodece it.

Comment: As far as I can remember the abort message should be in the dump and tell you the exception message

Comment: @AlanBirtles
This is the exception message:
Unhandled exception at 0x7578EDBB (ucrtbase.dll) in AAAAA.exe.1652.dmp: Fatal program exit requested.

Comment: Debug your program step by step and see where it crashes.

Comment: @yao that sounds like undefined behaviour. You should recheck your code.

Comment: @yao If that's indeed the complete call stack then you either have a badly thrashed stack, or perhaps a mismatch between the 32/64 bitness of the DMP file vs. the app. WinDbg could provide some more context and exception details. Probably VS, too, though I am not so familiar with the steps there.

Comment: I can't reprodece it, the dump file was collected on user's environment.